# Why hazelcast can not read data from treemap with generic record?

Tags: hazelcast

I have example in my local hazelcast:

```
    Map<Integer, TreeMap<Long, GenericRecord>> map = hzInstance.getReplicatedMap(TEST_MAP);
    TreeMap<Long, GenericRecord> zmeny = new TreeMap<Long, GenericRecord>();
    zmeny.put(1l, GenericRecordBuilder.compact("test").setString("string", "stringvalue").setInt32("integer", 123)
            .build());
    map.put(1, zmeny);

    Map<Integer, TreeMap<Long, GenericRecord>> a = hzInstance.getReplicatedMap(TEST_MAP);
    for (Entry<Integer, TreeMap<Long, GenericRecord>> ccc : a.entrySet()) {
        GenericRecord record = ccc.getValue().get(1l);
        System.out.println(record); // here I got exception
    }
```

so I am inserting map of treemap to hazelcast. Problem is when I want to read this data from hazelcast. I got example:

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Cannot read 4 bytes!
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.checkAvailable(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:670)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readInt(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:293)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.compact.CompactInternalGenericRecord.getInt32(CompactInternalGenericRecord.java:255)
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

when I debug I see that record is `DefaultCompactReader` which can not read data. It looks like it is empty. Any advice what I am doing wrong ?

**UPDATE1**

compact serialization is enabled. Without it I can not even put treemap to hazelcast:

```
            Config hzConfig = new Config();
    NetworkConfig network = hzConfig.getNetworkConfig();
    network.setPortAutoIncrement(false);
    network.getInterfaces().setEnabled(true).addInterface("127.0.0.1");
    network.getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
    hzConfig.getUserCodeDeploymentConfig().setEnabled(true);
    hzConfig.getSerializationConfig().getCompactSerializationConfig().setEnabled(true);
    HazelcastInstance hzInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hzConfig);
```

**UPDATE2**

When I debug code I can see this not working because of:
`com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.bufferpool.BufferPoolImpl.returnInputBuffer(BufferObjectDataInput)`

which clear input buffer. `StreamSerializerAdapter` with `TreeMap` is used instead of `CompactStreamSerializer`

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, you should enable Compact serialization explicitly, as it is still in BETA. (It will be promoted to stable status in the upcoming 5.2 release).

When you enable Compact serialization with a configuration like the below, the code snippet you shared works as expected, which I tested .

```java
config.getSerializationConfig().getCompactSerializationConfig().setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: it is enabled. Without it I can not put data to hazelcast

Comment: What Hazelcast version are you using? I tried the code snippet you shared with Compact serialization enabled on master, and it worked just fine.

Comment: 5.1.1 hz version

Comment: with java 17  version

Comment: OK, see my answer here https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/21902#issuecomment-1204937590

Comment: wow thx a lot what a quick response

Answer (score 0):

thx to mdumandag [this](https://%20https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/21902) is bug which will be fixed in 5.2